# MongoClient $in doesn't work with int array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm new to mongodb, I have a test collection like this:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5afce40ae1def619f8c591f1"), "location" : "shanghai", "version" : "1.14", "platform" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afce43ce1def619f8c591f3"), "location" : "beijing", "version" : "1.2", "platform" : 1 }
```

It works well in the shell:

```
db.test.aggregate([{$match: { 'location':{ $in:['beijing','shanghai'] }  , 'platform':{ $in:[1]}  }}])
```

And it does work in the java MongoClient like this :

```
 List<Bson> filter = Arrays.asList(
            Document.parse("{$match: { 'location':{ $in:['beijing','shanghai'] }  }}")
        );
 AggregateIterable<Document> doc = mongoClient.getDatabase(db).getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(filter);
```

When $in uses an int array it just doesn't work and return an empty array:

```
 List<Bson> filter = Arrays.asList(
            Document.parse("{$match: { 'location':{ $in:['beijing','shanghai'] }  , 'platform':{ $in:[1]}  }}")
        );
 AggregateIterable<Document> doc = mongoClient.getDatabase(db).getCollection(collectionName).aggregate(filter);
```

Comment: help ~-~ ~-~ ~-~

Comment: its working  ......

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
MongoCollection<Document> doc = db.getCollection("TestCollection1");
        List<Bson> filter = Arrays.asList(
                Document.parse("{$match: { 'location':{ $in:['beijing','shanghai'] }  , 'platform':{ $in:[1]}  }}")
            );
        AggregateIterable<Document> doc2= doc.aggregate(filter);
        Iterator iterator = doc2.iterator(); 
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Document plant = (Document) iterator.next();
         System.out.println(plant);
        }
```

**Output**

> Document{{_id=5afce40ae1def619f8c591f1, location=shanghai, version=1.14, platform=1.0}}
>   Document{{_id=5afce43ce1def619f8c591f3, location=beijing, version=1.2, platform=1.0}}

Comment: Still doesn't work.. At first I thought it was causing by a version conflict between mongo client and server,just now I switched mongo-java-driver version to 3.2.0 which is the same as mongo server ,but the result came back the same.